# Selecting Dropdown Option Based on Session Variable Using PHP

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I am using PHP to populate my options for a dropdown menu in HTML via Javascript append. It works so far, and I am using a conditional statement to only show the value for that team ID if the session variable is set. The issue is i need to display all the dropdown options (like the else/while statement in PHP) even when the session variable is set so people can still have that option to manually select another ID, but if session is set auto select the value that the session variable is set to.... otherwise just display the options selecting default option (1) like in my else statement. Any suggestion on how I should go about this? Thanks!

HTML

```
<td class="label_container">Team ID#</td>
            <td class="input_container">
            <select id="prepping_team" name="prepping_team"></select>
            </td>
```

JS

```
//Populate Team IDs
function get_prepping_team() {
$.ajax({
    url: './php/getprepping_team.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#prepping_team').append(data);
    }
});
};
```

PHP

```
//Grab Session (if set)
session_start();
$_SESSION['prepping_team'];

$prep_team = $_POST['prepping_team'];

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-type: multipart/form-data');

$logAuditFile = "../log/prepform.log";
$logModule = "getprepping_team.php";
include '/mnt/library/auditlog.php';

require("/mnt/library/configdb.php");        
include '/mnt/library/accessdb.php';

//Parse and store the db ini file, this will return an associative array
db_config_cables_test();
db_connect();

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pt_id FROM preppingteam;");
//IF SESISON VARIALBE IS SET
if(isset($_SESSION['prepping_team'])) {
    print "<option value=\"".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."\">".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."</option>";
    //print "<option value=\"".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."\">".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."</option>";
//OTHERWISE LOAD TEAM IDs
} else {
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        print "<option value=\"".$data['pt_id']."\">".$data['pt_id']."</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: try cleaning this question up. It's not very clear on what exactly you're asking/needing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last part of the code is not doing what you want. So correct it like this

**Update:**

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
   if(isset($_SESSION['prepping_team']) && $_SESSION['prepping_team'] == $data['pt_id'])
    {
    print "<option selected = 'selected'  value=\"".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."\">".$_SESSION['prepping_team']."</option>";    
    }
   else
    print "<option value=\"".$data['pt_id']."\">".$data['pt_id']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: interesting, your else is not in brackets is that some new php shorthand thing? But sadly that is not working, I can get it to do that, but the IDs are just 6 options all as "3". The IDs are 1,2,3,4,5 and 6, and it needs to display 1-6 and select 3 if the session varialbe is set to 3 or whatever. All that code does is display 3,3,3,3,3,3 in the dropdown :(

Comment: Is there a way I can apply this in my PHP? I know this is used in HTML and I found this at another stackoverflow post and tried modifying it, but I just need to use this within my PHP print statement:

<select name="prepping_name">
 <?php foreach($data AS $value) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php if($_SESSION['prepping_team'] == $value) echo 'selected'; ?>><?php echo $value; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
</select>

Comment: yes you can do.. but it will be slightly different

 while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        print "<option value=\"".$data['pt_id']."\" <?php if($_SESSION['prepping_team'] == $data['pt_id']) echo 'selected'; ?> >".$data['pt_id']."</option>";
    }

Comment: that didn't work... the variables are all different colors and looks weird in Coda 2 within that php and caused errors: while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
     if(isset($_SESSION['prepping_team'])) {
       print "<option value=\"".$data['pt_id']."\" <?php if($_SESSION['prepping_team'] == $data['pt_id']) echo 'selected'; ?> >".$data['pt_id']."</option>";    
     } else {
      print "<option value=\"".$data['pt_id']."\">".$data['pt_id']."</option>";
     }
   }

Comment: it will work
 while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { echo "<option value='".$data['pt_id']."' ".(($_SESSION['prepping_team'] == $data['pt_id'])?'selected="selected"':'')." >".$data['pt_id']."</option>"; }

Comment: haha ok well that worked, but now it is back to displaying only "3" and not the other options now... I have been trying this out all morning. you have been helpful so far, thank you very much.

Comment: it should have worked.. have you tried my update in the answer??

Comment: Oh it did!! Didn't see your updated answer, my bad. Thanks so much man. I didn't know the && portion could be applied that way to populate the IDs.

Comment: PROBLEM the data submits as a 1 and not a "3" no matter which option i choose?